# Do any of the Vaishnava Agamas recommend any Vedantic philosophies like Vishishtha Advaita or any other?

Tags: philosophy, vedanta, vaishnavism, agamas

Do any authentic Vaishnava Agama texts directly or explicitly recommend any Vedantic philosophies like the Advaita philosophy or any other?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69316/discussion-on-question-by-rakesh-joshi-do-any-of-the-vaishnava-agamas-recommend).

Comment: No Hindu scripture literally recommend any of Vedantic philosophies.

Comment: @brahmajijnasa thats good to know

Comment: I think Agamas are ancient than Vedantic philosophies (Advaita, Vishishtadvaita etc.)

Comment: @Pandya cos almost all vaishnavas following vedanta. Whereas its core is based on Agamas.